# display result of random equation with php

Tags: php, math

i have this php code

```
<?php
            $sum = '('.$interval1->format("%Y").'*12*1000)+('.$interval1->format("%M").'*12)+((1000/30)*'.$interval1->format("%d").')';
            echo $sum;
```

?>

this code will display

```
(33*12*1000)+(07*12)+((1000/30)*10)
```

how to display the result of this equation in php?

Comment: share the value of $interval1 please

Comment: the value of $interval1 Y is 33
the value of $interval1 M is 07

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: If you need to output the formula as a string as well as is answer as a number, you can create another variable to do the calculation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

eval($var) function will do the trick as shown below

```
echo eval("return ".$sum.";");
```